# Flag control by using SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to get output which is in Table A no duplication. Flag will be Y when table B event ID will have to matched with (A,B,C) otherwise flag will be N.

Table A

| Id | Name | Flag |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Mike | Y |
| 2 | Bill | Y |

Table B

| ID | EventId |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 1 | B |
| 1 | C |
| 1 | AAA |
| 1 | BBB |
| 2 | A |
| 2 | B |
| 2 | C |

Query:

```
SELECT 
    a.id, a.name 
FROM
    table a
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT b.id, b.eventid 
     WHERE eventid IN ('A', 'B', 'C')) ah ON ah.id = b.id
```

Comment: You missed `from` in the outer join.

Comment: How does EventId in TableB match to anything in TableA?

Comment: @Salman81 . . . It is not clear where `name` is coming from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation with `case`:

```
select id,
       (case when sum(case when eventid in ('A', 'B', 'C') then 1 else 0 end) = 3
             then 'Y' else 'N'
        end) as flag
from b
group by id;
```

The above assumes that id/event pairs are unique.  If they can be duplicated, you can instead use:

```
select id,
       (case when count(distinct case when eventid in ('A', 'B', 'C') then eventid end) = 3 then 'Y' else 'N' end) as flag
from b
group by id;
```

If what you want to do is *update* table a, then you can use these queries in an `update`:

```
update a
    set flag = (case when match_cnt = 3 then 'Y' else 'N' end)
    from a left join
         (select id,
                 sum(case when eventid in ('A', 'B', 'C') then 1 else 0 end) as match_cnt
          from b
          group by id
         ) b
         on a.id = b.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @TableA TABLE (Id int, Name varchar(20), Flag char(1))
;
INSERT INTO @TableA
    VALUES  
            (1, 'Mike', NULL)
        ,   (2, 'Bill', NULL)
        ,   (3, 'Sal' , NULL)
;
DECLARE @TableB TABLE (Id int, EventID varchar(20))
;
INSERT INTO @TableB
    VALUES  
            (1, 'A'  )
        ,   (1, 'B'  )
        ,   (1, 'C'  )
        ,   (1, 'AAA')
        ,   (1, 'BBB')
        ,   (2, 'A'  )
        ,   (2, 'B'  )
        ,   (2, 'C'  )
        ,   (3, 'AAA')
        ,   (3, 'BBB')
        ,   (3, 'A'  )
        ,   (3, 'B'  )
;

WITH MatchAll AS
    (
        SELECT
                    A.Id
                ,   Qty = SUM(CASE WHEN B.ID IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)
        FROM        @TableA A
        LEFT JOIN   @TableB B   ON  B.ID        =   A.ID
                                AND B.EventID   IN  ('A', 'B', 'C')
        GROUP BY A.Id, B.ID
    )

UPDATE
        Flag    =   CASE M.Qty WHEN 3 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END
FROM    @TableA     A
JOIN    MatchAll    M   ON  M.ID = A.ID

SELECT  
        A.*
FROM    @TableA     A
```